# substitute minus for plus symbol between 2 quotation marks

Tags: regex, vim

The original text is like

> a = a + "a + b" + c + "a + b" + c

How to use regex in vim to archive the following result:

1. to substitute - for + out of the every pair of quotation marks.

> a = a - "a + b" - c - "a + b" - c

2. to substitute - for + in every pair of quotation marks.

> a = a + "a - b" + c + "a - b" + c

I've tried lookbehind and lookahaed with lazy or greedy multiplier to get the result step by step. However, I want to know whether these is a general statement for such a case, which can make substitution clearly and beautifully.

Thanks

Comment: where do you used semicolons?

Comment: I think he means quotes "".

Comment: It should be quotes! thanks

Answer (score 1):

try the couple of cmds in vim:

for the first one:

```
s/\zs+\ze\s*"\|"\s*\zs+\ze/-/g
```

for the 2nd one:

```
s/"[^+"]*\zs+\ze[^+"]*"/-/g
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1.: \+(?=(?:[^"\n]*"[^"\n]*")*[^"\n]*$)
2.: \+(?=(?:[^"\n]*"[^"\n]*")*[^"\n]*"[^"\n]*$)
```

[Demo 1.](http://regex101.com/r/lJ5bR3/3)
[Demo 2.](http://regex101.com/r/jL1wK0/2)

The idea is simple: Match a `+` only if there's an even/uneven number of quotes behind it.

Explanation of the first pattern:

```
\+ // match "+"
(?= // assert there's an even number of quotes left
    (?:
        [^"\n]*" // consume one quote, and all text in front of it...
        [^"\n]*" //...twice
    )* //...as often as possible
    [^"\n]*$ // finally, assert there's no more quotes in this line.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\+(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

This will be for the first case.exclude `+` if between `"` and `"`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/44

```
\+(?=[^"]*"(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

This will be for the second case.If between `"` abd `"`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/45